# Computing a hole in a triangulated polygon mesh

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, computational-geometry

I'm working on a visualizer in WPF which has a function to display a cutting plane through a 3-D shape. For example, a 3-d geometry like this:

[image: Full Geometry]

... is cut with a plane. After cutting, the algorithm identifies all the unique outlines along the cutting plane and populates a list of line segments, in either CW or CCW winding order. Any simple polygon is easy to triangulate and render using the Cutting Ears algorithm, like this:

[image: Cut Plane Image] [image]

Given an input of the triangulation on the right, and the inner polyline visible on the plane surface on the left, is there an algorithm which can reconfigure the triangulation to construct a hole outlined by the polyline?

If there are algorithms already rolled in C# or another CLR language, I'd love to learn about them. I'm using the Point3D lists called for by WPF to describe MeshGeometry3D triangle meshes, but I can obviously fill any data structure if needed or spin my own class by studying other language code or pseudocode.

EDIT: See the accepted answer; I'm making use of the C# implementation of [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/), a Constrained Delaunay Triangulation. However, (images not to scale) the Poly2Tri algorithm (center) failed with a 780-segment polyline, while Cutting Ears (right) did not, until I stripped the inputs of their precision, supplying single precision values upcast as doubles instead of doubles. It now produces a different triangulation than Cutting Ears but respects the boundaries of the outer polyline.

[image: ComplexPoly] [image: ComplexCDT] [image: ComplexEars]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute a constrained Delaunay triangulation with the border segments as constraints. Determine an inner triangle. From there grow the area until you reach borders. As a positive side effect such a triangulation will have better shaped triangles.

[image: Constrained Delaunay of a zone]

Comment: I wish for that, but see my edited question; the CDT didn't work with a very complex (more than your example) closed concave polyline.

Comment: Two possible reasons: First, numerical tests in Delaunay triangulations should only rely on floatingpoint arithmetic. I don't know Poly2Tri well

Comment: Poly2Tri takes double precision floating point numbers as inputs. I did have to modify CuttingEars to get it to triangulate, by tightening its "same point detection" tolerences by a lot. I haven't tried that with Poly2Tri because, frankly, I haven't yet studied the paper it's based on and compared the code.

Comment: Sorry for the double post above, I hit the RETURN key: There are two possible reasons: First, you have probably projected and rotated your contour. This introduces numerical errors, and if the contour has selfintersections, this will almost certainly cause trouble. Second, I don't know Poly2Tri, but you should make sure that the library you use is numerically robust. Otherwise it may fail in difficult situations. The images above have been computed with my Fade2D library which copes with large and difficult data. But it is for C++ and I don't know if you can use it together with C#.

Comment: It's not difficult (just tedious) to port a C++ library. There are no projections or rotations; the polyline is built from triangle edges where the edges all have the same "x" coordinate in common. I'm also sure there are no self intersections in the polyline; the algorithm that generates them makes that impossible, and the error condition begins at a point where there are no self intersections, just a very gradual concavity.

Comment: OK, even with two extra orders of magnitude added to the tolerances with Poly2Tri I still don't get a good triangulation. But that wasn't the original question anyway. The original question is, paraphrased: "Given a triangulation and a polyline within the bounds of the triangulation, is there an algorithm that will transform the triangulation such that it contains a hole described by the polyline?"

Comment: Put the border of the original triangulation as well as the polyline inside into a constrained Delaunay triangulator which works for your data. Is there anything in your original question that is not solved by that? This is a standard solution for which libraries exist. Even if you can come up with a better solution - which is unlikely unless I misunderstood your question - then you will still need to cope with the problem that orientation tests of your new solution won't work reliably with floatingpoint arithmetic.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18875/discussion-between-rob-perkins-and-geom)

Answer (score 0):

Had to resolve the exact same problem when making a export/import plugin between SketchUp and 3DSMax. Sketchup use a concept or outer and inner loops while 3DS Max is pure geometry.

Sadly, I don't have the plugin around, so I will try to remember it as best as I can:

```
foreach point in outerLoop
{
    // Loop over all other point to find the nearest valid one
    foreach otherPoint in both outerLoop and all innerLoops where otherPoint is not point
    {
        if otherPoint is adjacent to point
            reject otherPoint 

        if distance between point and otherPoint is bigger than previous distance
            reject otherPoint 

        // Test is vector is point outside the geometry in case of convexe shapes
        if cross product of vector from (point - adjacent point) and (point - nearest point) is pointing away from cross product of vectors of (point - both adjacents point)
            reject otherPoint 

        nearestPoint = otherPoint
    }

    for the two adjacentPoint of nearestPoint
    {
        if adjacentPoint is also adjacent to point
            make triangle(point, adjacentPoint, nearestPoint)
        if cross product of vector from (point - adjacent point) and (point - nearest point) is pointing in the same direction as cross product of vectors of (point - both adjacents point)
            make triangle(point, adjacentPoint, nearestPoint)
    }
}

repeat the above for innerLoops point while only checking against other innerLoops

make triangle function should check if the triangle already exist from previous iteration.
```

It's not super pretty and is kinda brute, but it works with a unlimited number of inner loops and create always the best triangles possible.

I'm pretty sure there would be way to improve its performance, but I never gave it enough time.

Comment: Maybe... is this algorithm helped if the points are already sorted in a winding order, that is the next point in the array is guaranteed to be the nearest one?

Comment: @RobPerkins: Yeah... All loop has to be sorted in order first, otherwise finding the adjacent one in the loop is gonna be tricky. But the nearest one the algo seek is not only in the same loop, it's in the other loop, and there is no way to know which one is the nearest.